# WPF layout grid layout any size row but with minimum height

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I am quite new to XAML and I just can't figure how to do create this layout.

So imagine a layout with a header, main area and footer. Each region is simply an image control.

I am using a grid definition of:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

So all the empty space is used up by the main area. This is great for portrait windows but however when the window is resized to be landscape. The footer and header eats up all the space and there is hardly any left for the main area and infact I can't see the image for the main area as there is no space left.

So is it possible to specify a minimum height for the main area? I tried using MinHeight to the image control in the main area but it make no difference. I am hoping by specifying a minimum height, this will force the header and footer regions to be smaller and hence those images will scale to maintain aspect ratios and hence their widths will also become smaller. Hope that makes sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is kirotab's answer not suitable to you like`<RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight=HEIGHT]/>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work out so he might need to change the Footer and Header content heights in order to make them smaller.

Comment: simply add MinHeight and MaxHeight to your Rowdefinitions

Comment: I didn't realise the row definition had a minimum height attribute. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @rukiman As I suspected if you only put `MaxHeight` it will not be enough for your desired behavior, The header and the footer will still be as high as the elements inside them, so maybe it's a good idea to bind to some property the size of these elements if you want to leave the row definitions  as `Auto` and on resize set your values (or if using mobile devices on orientation change)

Comment: adding maxheight did not work. And it seems like the Auto is causing the header and footer not to become smaller.

Comment: @rukiman Man did you read at all what I wrote ... I've explained that it will happen and **you need to resize the controls inside the header and the footer if you leave your height to Auto** (Explained the reason in the answer and posted links to understand how setting with different grid length types is affecting the view ....) MinHeight on the main row is only ensuring that this control will be at least of the specified minimum size...

Answer (score 6):

When you specify `*` as your `Height` or `Width` for rows or columns respectively you tell them to take % left after the other calculations. If you have two columns with `*` as `Width` than they take 50% of the left space each.

When you specify `Auto` it's taking into account the size of the controls inside.

There is property `MinHeight` for row and column definitions

So you could try to set `MinHeight` of the main row but I think it may not work, and you could also **specify the size of the elements in the header and the footer rows** to be of certain size (you could do that only on landscape mode and leave it as is in portrait)

**Edit - added links for reference**

[GridLength Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

[GridUnitType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Auto - The size is determined by the size properties of the content object.
- Pixel - The value is expressed as a pixel.
- Star - The value is expressed as a weighted proportion of available space.